# Joint probability function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am currently having a little dilemma as to how to solve a probability problem I found on the internet. Here are the density functions:

Let x and y be random variables such that

```
f(x; y) = 0,5; x > 0; y > 0; x < 2; x > y
f(x; y) = 1/4; -2 < x < 0; 0 < y < 2
```

The first question requires me to find the MSE estimator of x given y (mean squared error estimator), however to do that I will first have the conditional distribution which is given by:

`fx(x|y) = f(x;y)/fy(y)`

In other words, I need to find the marginal density fy(y) but my problem here is that there are two density functions. Should I treat them separately (0>x>-2 and 2>x>0) in which case I would have two estimators or should just add them together?

Any help or tip would be really appreciated,

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ is proportional to the joint density of $(X,Y)$, with an appropriate scaling factor such that the total area under the conditional density is $1$.  Thus, we know that $$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \begin{cases} c/2, & y < x < 2 \\ c/4, & -2 < x < 0, \end{cases}$$ for some suitable constant $c$ **with respect to $x$** and for $0 < y < 2$.  Immediately we see scaling factor $c$ is a function of $y$, since we require $$1 = \int_{x \in [-2,0] \cup [y,2]} f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) \, dx = 2\frac{c}{4} + (2-y)\frac{c}{2},$$ hence $$c = \frac{2}{3-y}$$ and the desired conditional density is $$f_{X \mid Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3-y}, & y < x < 2 \\ \frac{1}{2(3-y)}, & -2 < x < 0. \end{cases}$$

That said, since your joint density has no parameters to speak of, I am not sure what you mean by "MSE of $x$ given $y$."

---

You are actually asking for the [Minimum mean square error estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error) of $x$ given $y$, which is the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$:  $$\hat x_{\text{MMSE}} (y) = \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y] = \int_{x \in [-2,0] \cup [y,2]} x f_{X|Y}(x|y) \, dx.$$
It is trivial to calculate this once you have the conditional density as shown above; I leave it as an exercise to show that you get $$\hat x_{\text{MMSE}}(y) = \frac{2-y^2}{2(3-y)}.$$

Comment: I see, I did not think of that way. I just derived the marginal densities from the joint probabilities and then resolved it in two parts. The question is as follows: "What is the MMSE estimator of x given y? Is this estimator biased or unbiased?". I take it I would have to integrate the conditional density times x to find the MMSE estimator (according to the definition).

Comment: The density function is basically a uniform distribution rectangular from -2 to 0 and triangular from 0 to 2. The MMSE should be the mean of each? I am lost.

Comment: @Fenrir Please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you heropup, I know understand how to tackle this sort of problem. However, I am still wondering why can't I solve it using marginal densities and finding the conditional densities (fx(x|y) = f(x;y)/fy(y)) for each part.